# Failed authentication results in blank page

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

Here's a trivial handler for authentication...

```
public class AuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthOptions>
{
    public AuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) :
        base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
       return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Failed"));
    }
}
```

It results in the correct Http status, but the screen is blank.

Is the handler also responsible for doing a redirect? If so, why does the system need a result returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a failed authentication should be handled in an override of...

`Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)`

And a failed authorization should be handled in an override of...

`Task HandleForbiddenAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)`.